# highlighting color for single item in listview based edittext input field

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android. 
In my project i displayed the "LIST VIEW". 
when i click the button,I am taking edit text value then i want to matches to any one item in "LIST VIEW" i need to highlight that item with color. 
How can i highlight specific list item? thank you

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_scan:
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PurchaseOrderLineItemActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.scan_popup, null);
                final EditText upc_edit = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.upc_text);
                final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_close);
                Button mLogin = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.upc_scan);
                mBuilder.setView(mView);
                final AlertDialog dialog = mBuilder.create();
                dialog.show();
                mLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                     String result = upc_edit.getText().toString();
                     String item_result,Received_items;
                     boolean no_upc_match = true;

                     for(ItemLineList itemLineLists : List) {
                            item_result =  itemLineLists.getItem_barcode();
                            if(result.equals(itemLineLists.getItem_barcode()) ) {
                                 Received_items = itemLineLists.getScan_item_quantity();
                                int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(Received_items);
                                present_value_int++;
                                String final_received_items = String.valueOf(present_value_int);
                                itemLineLists.setScan_item_quantity(final_received_items);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                dialog.dismiss();
                                no_upc_match = false;
                                 break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
//                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no match" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Easiest way if there will be only one item selected at a time -> Have an integer in your adapter class initialized with -1. And set it to matched position  and validate it inside `onBingViewHolder()`.  For selected multiple item you better add a flag to your dataset object .

Comment: I am not selecting item. instead of  i need to check with input value in list view and I am not using recyclerview.  thank you

Comment: Your question is way too broad right now. That's what i said if value from editText matches any value from the list then set the matched item position to adapter.  Can value from editText could match multiple list item or it can match to only single item ?

Comment: It will match for single item

Answer (score 0):

```
  int i = 0; 
  for(ItemLineList itemLineLists : List)
   {
     .
     .
     .
      if(result.equals(itemLineLists.getItem_barcode()) )
        {
           getView(i,listView).setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);                 
        }
      else
       {

       }
     i += 1;
  }
```

**`Function to Get View:-`**

```
public View getView(int pos, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (pos < firstListItemPosition || pos > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
    } else {
        final int childIndex = pos - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, Please Tick it as answer if it really worked for you.